# Return to main page after javascript alert in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to ask if how to redirect the page to the index page after the action returns an alert in asp.net mvc.

In my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<RMSystem.Models.ack_vw>

<table id="ack">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Reference ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Referred By</th>
        <th>Referral Bonus</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Date Acknowledged</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var refp in Model) { 
   <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.rf_id)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.Fullname)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.referredby)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.p_amount)</td>
        <td>
            @if (refp.p_isactive == true)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Send Acknowledgement", "Update_Rec")
            }
            else { 
                 <text>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.statusname)</text>
            }
        </td>
        <td>@Html.Action("Date_Ack", new  { appr_id = refp.appr_id})</td>
   </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>



public ActionResult Update_Rec()
    {

        SendEmailController email = new SendEmailController();
        var Emails = (from s in db.rms_users_roles_vw
                           where s.r_id == 1 && s.u_isactive == true
                           select s.user_email).ToArray();
        var incc = (from s in db.rms_users_roles_vw
                           where s.r_id == 2 && s.u_isactive == true
                           select s.user_email).ToArray();

        var body = "This is to notify you that referrer &nbsp;" + ref_name + "has already acknowledged the referral bonus entry. <br>After one month, another notification will be sent for the processing of his bonus in the next payout.<br>Thanks.";
        var subject = "Notification = Referral Bonus Process";
        email.Send(Emails, incc, body, subject);

        return Content("<script>alert('You have acknowledged your referral bonus!');</script>"); ;
    }
```

When I clicked the ok button it shows nothing and doesn't refresh the page.
Any idea how to redirect it to the index page?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What button? Show your view so we can understand what your trying to do

Comment: @StephenMuecke, see edited question. It's not a button actually. It's a link and when I clicked that link, the function for that should return a confirmation alert then redirect back to the index page.

Comment: Its a link so it redirects! What are your really trying to do? Is the view you have shown the `Index` page (i.e. you want to stay on the same page?) - in which case you ajax to call you method and display the alert in javascript

Comment: yeah it's a link and it should redirect but I want that upon clicking there should also an alert about the confirmation.

Comment: Which page are you wanting to redirect to? And which is the view you have shown in the question?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you can try ajax. Something like below:

View

```
@model IEnumerable<RMSystem.Models.ack_vw>

    <table id="ack">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Reference ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Referred By</th>
            <th>Referral Bonus</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Date Acknowledged</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var refp in Model) { 
       <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.rf_id)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.Fullname)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.referredby)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.p_amount)</td>
            <td>
                @if (refp.p_isactive == true)
                {
                    <a href="#" onClick="SendNotification('@ref.rf_id')">Send Acknowledgement</a>
                }
                else { 
                     <text>@Html.DisplayFor(model => refp.statusname)</text>
                }
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Action("Date_Ack", new  { appr_id = refp.appr_id})</td>
       </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
function SendNotification(var refId)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Update_Rec")',
        data: { refId: refId },
        success: function(result){
            if(result.Success){
              alert('You have acknowledged your referral bonus.');
              window.location.href= '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
            }
            else{
              alert(result.ErrorMsg);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, thrownError){
          alert(thrownError);
        }
      });
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Update_Rec(int refId)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    string errorMsg = "";

    try
    {
        //Codes to send email...

        isSuccess = true;
        errorMsg = "";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
        errorMsg = ex.Message;
    }

    return Json( new { Success = isSuccess, ErrorMsg = errorMsg });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Content("<script type="text/javascript">alert("You have acknowledged your referral bonus");window.location.href = "index.aspx("or any page")";</script>");
```

Try This

Comment: I'm using mvc here. why is it aspx? what's the syntax for mvc then?

Comment: @IamGlads it's just url path so in mvc default it will be: `window.location.href = "/Home/Index";`

Comment: Yes, It's just url. you can use any path here."index.aspx("or any page")"